# Alignment of UILabel and word wrapping with right-to-left language

Tags: ios, internationalization, autolayout, arabic, right-to-left

I have a view that has an image, and to the left it is a long block of text that may take up multiple lines.  In English, the first line might be full, and on the second line it may only take up half of the left side of the screen. When using Arabic, should the text be aligned towards the right side, where the first line is full, but the second line takes up half of the line and is aligned with the right?

I am using Auto Layout.  Is there something, like the hugging settings, that I want to adjust?

Comment: What happens when you change the settings in the iOS simulator to Arabic? It should change the right-to-left language settings and you can check your app.

Comment: Is does change. but should it look like the justification I see on this webpage, where each line after word wrapping is lined up on the left side, or should it be aligned on the right side?